# how can I get the value from json?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this json: `{message:"a"}`

I send the request by ajax and then get the response:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#l").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"index/judement",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                    data:JSON.stringify({
                        number:$("#number").val(),
                        password:$("#password").val()
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error: function () {
                      alert("...");
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

And then I get this:
[image]
but I just want to get `a`!! not all the json! how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this remove  `JSON.stringify()` so that you will get value as object not as `string`

Try this

```
alert(data.message);
```

This will only alert a,

if you will use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.message));
```

it will alert "a"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.message));
```

Comment: oh! So simple, I google more than two hours can not find a solution!